# Application on Windows 7 disappears straight after starting, but still visible in "process list" 

Tags: windows-7, java, application-launch

I'm trying to run [FigTree](http://tree.bio.ed.ac.uk/software/figtree/) on Windows 7.

I think it's a Java application, but I'm not positive about that.

I have successfully used it before on Windows 7, but now when I click the figtree.exe (or a shortcut to it) I get the usual "this is an application from the Internet are you sure you want to run it". I pick OK but nothing seems to happen. When I check on the Task Manager it doesn't show up in programs, but it does show up in processes, using zero CPU and about a MB of memory. If I try clicking the .exe again I get multiple copies of the process running.

In the course of fiddling with it I noticed that if I kill the javaw.exe process the figtree icon pops up and a message objects "an error occurred while starting the application: access is denied"

Comment: First off, right-click on the download, choose `Properties` and `Unblock` the file, if you trust it. Then right-click on it and choose to `Run as Administrator`. This will eliminate security issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application is trying to do something that requires administrative rights, but doesn't have those rights and so is stuck in a loop.

If you know what it is and trust it, run it as admin. (Right click, "Run as administrator")

Comment: i tired running as admin and ti didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Try running the application from the command line, it will usually give you a better idea of what's happening and show you any errors. Try updating your java to the latest version as well.